# CSS or JS max. character <h2> and replace end with "..."

Tags: javascript, css

I assume my title basically summed it all up.

I have a `<h2>` title, and I want it to have a max character property, be it CSS or javascript, so that whenever this maximum limit is passed, the title's end is replaced by ... (three dots).

Thank you very much in advance.
An example can be viewed here: http://themeforest.net/forums/thread/now-accepting-bargain-submissions/23205 (see the title)

P.S. Any idea why I had to create a new user? the login-feature through google doesn't recognize my previous user :(

Comment: That's just an example which works the way I'd like my website to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Pure javascript style

```
var maxLen = 30;
var titles = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
for(i in titles){
  if(titles[i].innerHTML.length > maxLen){
    titles[i].innerHTML = titles[i].innerHTML.substr(0, maxLen)+"...";
  }
}
```

Doing this by CSS you could set width for `h2` with `overflow: hidden`

Comment: Hey, thanks a bunch. I actually did it with CSS, using oferflow:hidden, but it just cut out in the middle of a letter, and that didn't look good. Trying your script now.

Comment: Well, I tried it, but it doesn't work :S. I assume I am doing something wrong; I've added the code in the head of my HTML within <script type="text/javacsript"></script> and also tried tweaking the maxLen var, with 10 or so, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: You have to execute this on dom ready (when all h2 elements are loaded). `<script type="text/javacsript"> window.onload = function(){ ... } </script>`

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I tried it again. I replaced those ... in your last example with your above code. I tried putting it in the head and the body, neither worked.

Have a look: http://pastebin.com/y7D3kZqk

Comment: change `text/javacsript` to `text/javascript` :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS by specifying a fixed width for H2 elements, or with JavaScript:

```
function shorten(el, maxlength) {
    for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        if (el[i].innerText.length > maxlength) {
            el[i].innerHTML = el[i].innerText.substr(0, maxlength) + "&hellip;";
        }
    }
}
window.onload = function() {
    shorten(document.getElementsByTagName('h2'), 20);
}
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, as the code below as well as this one aren't working. Any hints?

Comment: I edited my code. Try putting this in your head section. As Anpher said, the page has to load all the H2 elements before executing the code, so attach it to the `onload` event. Else it will be executed before the whole page is loaded and wont find any H2 elements to shorten.

Comment: Sorry, still nothing. I created a function called init() with your code and load it in <body onload="init()">, yet it doesn't work. You can see it here: http://pastebin.com/9iREKXrZ

Please be patient with me, I am new to javascript functions, and loading beforehand. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to put it in `<body onload>`. Just put my code in a `script` tag in your `head` section.

Answer (score 0):

If using a hellip is not necessary, you can consider this pure-css solution:

```
h2 {
    max-width: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h2:before {
    content: " "; /* unicode space Alt+255 */
    display: block;
    background: url(shadow.png) top right repeat-y;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
```

shadow.png is small horizontal gradient from transparency to your background color.
Unfortunately, there is some problem in IE.

Comment: Woah, that's stunning. I tried it, and it works, though when I use the alt+255 blank space, it shows a diagonal square with a '?'.

Comment: Strange. Does your page have utf-8 encoding? Anyway, you can use other technique, like `content: "."; padding-left: 1000px;`
Other way is to add at the end of header tag some container `<h2>My TItile<span class="shadow"></span></h2>` where .shadow class is the same with :before. This should solve IE issues.

Comment: Hey, I sadly realised it would work, but it doesn't apply to what I need. Please have a look at my title (it must allow 2-lined titles, so if I use CSS and put a max-width, it'd only work on 1-lined h2 titles. >> http://i45.tinypic.com/2q03889.jpg